# ListView Recycle

Tags: android, listview

Regarding the lisview recycle, I'm reusing the views with viewholder, but now I need to add a number of Views(ImageViews and textviews) not clearcut( the number of views isnt always the same).

How can I add these items, without create a new view on every getView() method and without affecting the performance of the list?﻿

Comment: Can you share the code of your adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

No way to create different layouts without overriding `getView()`. You can reuse as much view types as you want, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row/4777306#4777306) answer.

If you have perfomance issue, try a new widjet [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/preview/material/ui-widgets.html#recyclerview), available at `Support-V7` library.

Answer (score 0):

my strategy to implement what you described without creating new view every time getView() is called, is:

let's say you have at the most 10 image views.  your view xml will contain 10 ImageView items, 
but when getView() been called - you'll set the visibility of the un-needed elements to View.GONE, and the only ones you needed to View.Visible.

working great for me, and that's the only why not to create new view...

Comment: So many views in xml and viewholder will not decrease the scroll performance?

Comment: from my experience, as long as you play with this amount of views visibility (and not much more) , the UI thread (and scroll speed) will not be affected.   besides that - you really not have better solution.  as @dimetil said - using RecyclerView can be better to use this case (with my approch), because it have property -         mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false) , which adressed exactly this issue of changing dynmically a lot the view params..